# Flex - condition in binding (for TextInput prop. text)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

For example `<s:TextInput id="sd" text="{if () {0} else if() {1} else {2}}"/>`

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: You should change the accepted answer in this case.

Comment: please rephrase your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function to implement your logic:

```
private function foo( value : String = "" ) : int
{
  if ( value == 'a')
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else if ( value == 'b' )
  {
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

then:

```
<s:TextInput id="source" text=""/>

<s:TextInput id="sd" text="{foo( source.text )}"/>
```

If you type "a" or "b" in the first TextInput the value in the second will change to reflect the current state.

Comment: That's not binding though.  Nothing in this code will make sd.text change whenever source.text changes.  I'm pretty sure this will throw a compiler warning because functions can't be made Bindable, unless they are special "get" or "set" functions.

Comment: Did you try it? It works.... the function is Bindable. The compiler warns you to name the event (which I didn't in the example) but that's not required. I updated my example to give the binding event a name to make the warning go away.

Comment: @Flextras The syntax is valid. It is like using the BindingUtils.bindSetter function (I think). You are not binding to a function, but rather running the value through a function and getting the return result when the bindings execute. You can even do it for as many bindable values as you wish. *edit* Although the bindable meta tag on the function is useless. Just get rid of it.

Comment: Also, it's not just limited to functions. You can execute any valid statement that returns a value. I use the tournery operator all the time ```<s:TextInput text="{(this.selected)? 'True' : 'False'}"/>``` will display true or false whenever bindings execute on this.selected. Fun stuff! :)

Comment: Points for the ternary operator! Might get hard to read the code with a nested "else if" but it should work fine.

Comment: bpanulla and drkstr are right.  Except you don't need a Bindable tag on top of the function.  The binding is already set by `source.text`.

Comment: Fascinating; I'm reviewing the generated ActionScript; it creates an anonymous function as an argument to mx.Binding.Binding; which runs the 'foo(source.text)' and returns either the results or null.  But, the Bindable metadata on the function is not needed for this to work. I can't tell what this accomplishes.

Comment: Apparently it accomplishes nothing :) I just wanted to verify it before I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I've read in amazon.com/AdvancED-Flex-4-Shashank-Tiwari/dp/1430224835 that developer should use as less bind tag as possible. Is it true? Due to book, binding can slow app up to several seconds.

Comment: Yes. Use bindings only where necessary. Also, remember to remove Event Listeners you add after they've done their job.

Answer (score 1):

No; that's too complicated for the default binding mechanism.  But, you didn't provide the full condition so it's hard to direct you explicitly.

When you implement the property you want to use as the binding source, dispatch an event.  Something like this in the set method:

```
public function set myBindableProperty(value:something):void{
 _myBindableProperty = value;
 dispatchEvent(new Event('myBindablePropertyChanged'));
}
```

Then add an event listener:

```
myComponentWithBindableProperty.addEventListener('myBindablePropertyChanged', onmyBindablePropertyChanged);
```

And finally, perform your binding action in the event handler

```
public function onmyBindablePropertyChanged(event:Event):void{
 if(){
  sd.text = 0;
 } else if(){
  sd.text = 1;
 } else {
  sd.text = 2;
 }
}
```

Internally; the MXML binding syntax does; basically; something like what I just described.  It's slightly more complex; but that is the gist.

Comment: Kind of overly complex don't you think?

Comment: Compared to what is done under the hood in generated ActionScript; no I don't think so.

Comment: That's not the point.  The less code the developer sees, the better, which is why we have shortcuts like the curly braces.

Comment: @J_A_X I believe this approach is significantly more flexible than using Binding.  "Less code" is not better, in fact there are many times when developers choose more code because something else is deemed as more important.  Frameworks are a prime example; they are chosen due to perceived gains in long term maintenance not because of less code.

Comment: If you're using Flex, you're using *less code* since you're not recreating the whole component library and other utils.  You don't see that code, you just use it to create whatever you want meaning that your end project has less perceived code. What you're doing is redoing what binding does for you, hence adding more code to your codebase and increasing complexity.

Comment: @J_A_X If you use Flex, you may be writing less code; but that is not the same as using less code.  In this case, I have an event listener instead of binding syntax in MXML.  The set method would be similar; and the method to make the change is similar.